# Sorting cell table columns populated from gwt rpc not working

Tags: java, gwt

I have a problem trying to sort specific columns from a cell table, whcih is populated from the DB, using RPC. Basically I'm trying to sort the family name column alphabetically, and it's just not working. Table gets fully populated, but sorting does not work.

Any ideas why ?

Thanks in advance

```
// Create the family name column.
    final TextColumn<ContactInfo> familyNameColumn = new TextColumn<ContactInfo>() {

        @Override
        public String getValue(ContactInfo object) {
            return object.getFamilyName();
        }
    };
    table.setColumnWidth(familyNameColumn, 20, Unit.PCT);

    // Make the family name sortable
    familyNameColumn.setSortable(true);


// Add the columns
    table.addColumn(familyNameColumn, UserMenuConstants.FAMILY_NAME_COLUMN);
    table.addColumn(familyAdministratorColumn, UserMenuConstants.FAMILY_ADMINISTRATOR_COLUMN);
    table.addColumn(apartmentNuberColumn, UserMenuConstants.FAMILY_APARTMENT_NUMBER_COLUMN);
    table.addColumn(emailColumn, UserMenuConstants.EMAIL_ADDRESS_COLUMN);
    table.addColumn(phoneNumberColumn, UserMenuConstants.PHONE_NUMBER_COLUMN);

    DBGetContactInfoAsync rpcService = (DBGetContactInfoAsync) GWT.create(DBGetContactInfo.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpcService;
    String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "DBGetContactInfoImpl";
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

    rpcService.getContacts(new AsyncCallback<List<ContactInfo>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<ContactInfo> result) {

            table.setRowCount(result.size());

            ListDataProvider<ContactInfo> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<ContactInfo>();
            dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);

            List<ContactInfo> list = dataProvider.getList();
            for (ContactInfo contactInfo : result) {
                list.add(contactInfo);
            }

            ListHandler<ContactInfo> listHandler = new ListHandler<ContactInfo>(result);

            listHandler.setComparator(familyNameColumn, new Comparator<ContactInfo>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(ContactInfo o1, ContactInfo o2) {
                    return o1.getFamilyName().compareTo(o2.getFamilyName());
                }
            });

            table.addColumnSortHandler(listHandler);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two copies of your data: `result` and `list`. The `list` is connected with `dataProvider`:

```
List<ContactInfo> list = dataProvider.getList();
```

and the `listListener` is connected with `result`:

```
ListHandler<ContactInfo> listHandler = new ListHandler<ContactInfo>(result);
```

so you are displaying `list` but sorting the `result`.

Just replace

```
new ListHandler<ContactInfo>(result);
```

with

```
new ListHandler<ContactInfo>(list);
```

and it works.

**EDIT:**

You can make it even easier and pass the `result` to the `ListDataProvider` constructor:

```
new ListDataProvider<ContactInfo>(result);
```

Then, you don't need to copy values to the `list` and just do

```
new ListHandler<ContactInfo>(dataProvider.getList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Move most of the code in your onSuccess method out of there - there is no reason to call it each time a data is loaded. For example, you can/should set a Comparator only once, etc.

Tell your table which column to use for sorting:

```
table.getColumnSortList().push(familyNameColumn);
```

When you finish loading new data, tell your table to sort it:

```
ColumnSortEvent.fire(table, table.getColumnSortList());
```